# System Stalled in middle of Upgrade to 13.10

Tags: upgrade

Now that an upgrade is in process the window indicating what stages are occurring with check-boxs is shadowed over and stuck in preparing to configure desktop. Does it normally stay at this stage without the orange status bar creeping forward at all? It has been stuck in one spot for about 30 mins.

Comment: Please append a screenshot, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should wait. Do you have a way to find out, if it's downloading something?
If it really fails, press CTRL-ALT-F1 followed by CTRL-ALT-DEL to reboot the pc cleanly.

Open the console, and run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This should continue the upgrade process.
If you cannot login to the GUI, press CTRL-ALT-F1 and log in here, to run the command.

If you have any problem now, please post it here.

Btw: If you have any important data to save, you might want to do it before reboot to an external drive.

Comment: I ended up rebooting before I saw your comment on a clean boot. I ran the command line you offered and rsyslog is not configured. Here is the error, posted below. I don't think I can go about clean install without starting over. I just want it to be configured correctly.//dpkg: error processing ubuntu-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:rsyslog
 ubuntu-minimal E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)